# How to add a new column with specific data into a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

So I am currently using data manipulation techniques to manipulate data in R. My dataset has CHILDID(fname), Channels, delta, alpha and other attributes. it is an EEG data(refer to pic below). Every ChildID(fname) has 14 channels(AF3, AF4, F3, F8, O1, P7, T8 etc.). I also have a group table which groups channels into three categories(1,2,3) for every CHILDID(fname).

[image: Dataframe]

So like my task is to add a column to the data frame named group which states the group no. of every channel.
The groups variable is present in table form as follows:

> groups<-cutree(hc2, k=3)
>
> print(groups)

[image]

The final outcome should be like this:

fname             Channel     delta  theta ................ Group

901.01.257....      AF3     55.1   9.3  ................   1

Comment: So where is the issue? Do you know how to append a column to a data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `match` to match `channel` column of dataframe with `names` of `groups`, get the corresponding group number and add it as new column.

```
m6$group <- groups[match(m6$channel, names(groups))]
```